# Commonly used android configuration environment setups?

Tags: android, development-environment, android-studio

So I've started using the new Google/Jetbrains [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) today and I cant seem to find an environment configuration setup that I'm happy with for android, in Xcode you can do stuff like set up a file that contains lots of different build configurations for things like local testing, preview testing on a live server, etc..

I'm testing out Android Studio and I'm enjoying it so far but I cant find anything like that.

If something like that doesn't exist for Android Studio, then say I wanted an IDE independent place to manage that stuff, is there a commonly used/accepted practice for that sort of thing for Android?

Thanks

Comment: you probably want to look at gradle

Comment: Jetbrains, not Jetbeans :]